# When jquery function is triggered, it posts data 10 times instead of once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jquery function that is triggered when a user clicks a button. In such condition, the value extracted is send to another page where the data is added to the database.

Now when ever I click once, the data is submitted exactly 10 times. Can anyone tell me why is it happening multiple times and exact 10 times in different scenario?

I have prevented the entry in to database from second time onwards but that is not cool.

The function is something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".good" ).click(function( event ) {
    var x = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post( "actionbuttons.php", { good: x }, function( data ) {
        $("#goodbad"+x).load('counts/goodbad.php?dataid='+x);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: The listener is added 10 times !

Comment: Some html please... But, try to „delegate” event like $('#page').on('click, '.good', function(evt){...}). This way, the event is not emited from every child (and, as bonus, is valid if you add '.good' after)

Comment: Perhaps the issue lies on `actionbuttons.php`? Is your insert query accidentally in a loop? What happens if you add `console.log(x);` after you assign x to the button's id? Does that get logged 10 times?

Comment: even if i place it as
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".good" ).click(function( event ) {
    var x = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(x);
});
});
the popup comes ten times and i may have any number of such buttons with dynamic id that is what i need to fetch.

Comment: Is your script in a loop that's being included 10 times? Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8rpj/) that demonstrates you can have a listener for multiple identical classes, and only the actively clicked element will trigger. You may want to throw in an `event.preventDefault();` to see if that's the cause, or you may have some other listener for those elements that's being triggered as well.